# Angular FormGroup and formcontrol

Tags: angular

Am using the concept of formgroups, and am trying to display the value using formgroup that is fg.Id.The value can be "abc:xyz"  .So using the below way am able to display the value for the Id as abc:xyz

```
<div class="form-group>
    <label for="Id">Id</label>
    <input
      id="Id"
      [formControl]="fg.Id"
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
    />
  </div>
```

Add on the page I have an other place where I have to display the value of Id after the ":".That is xyz as a LineNumber.How can I use the same parameter from the formgroup in this case.I wanted to do something like below, how to achieve it.

```
<div class="form-group>
    <label for="Id">Id</label>
    <input
      id="Id"
      [formControl]="fg.Id.ToString().split(':')[1]"
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
    />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and please don't forget to import ReactiveFormsModule in your modul file:

```
<form [formGroup]="fg" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Id">Id</label>
    <input
      id="Id"
      formControlName="id"
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
    />
  </div>
  <hr>
  <p> splitedValue: {{ splitedValue }}</p>
  <br>
  <p> validationStatus: {{ validationStatus }}</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">getFormValue</button>
</form>
---------------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-group',
  templateUrl: './form-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-group.component.css']
})
export class FormGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  fg: FormGroup;
  splitedValue: number;
  validationStatus: string;

  private yourValidation = [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.maxLength(100),
    Validators.minLength(5),
    Validators.pattern(/.+:.+/)
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl('', this.yourValidation)
    });
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    this.splitedValue = this.fg.value.id.split(':')[1];
    this.validationStatus = this.fg.status;
    console.log(this.fg.value);
  }
}
```